# Tem como fazer teste unitário em ASP?

Tags: testes-de-unidade, asp

Estou precisando de uma ajuda para fazer teste unitário em ASP para um projeto de qualidade de software. É possível fazer isto?

Lembrando que é ASP clássico.

Comment: Trocando de tecnologia :)

Comment: Infelizmente não é possível :/

Comment: Não faz sentido. Teste unitário testa comportamento do código, verificando se são produzidas determinadas saídas de acordo com os dados entrados. A saída de um Asp (bem como Asp.Net, xhtml, etc.) é uma interface gráfica. Então você não precisa de testes unitários e sim de testes de UI. Estes testes consideram o código gerado para o browser e não o código que você escreveu em Asp. Portanto, desde que o código gerado seja html e JavaScript, as ferramentas de teste são as mesmas independentemente da tecnologia que tem por baixo. Para testar UI a partir do browser, dê uma olhada no **Selenium**.

Comment: é possível usando frameworks para ASP.. tal como temos no PHP e em diversas outras linguagens do tipo.

Answer (score 7):

O ASP clássico (Active Server Pages), só pra deixar claro, não é uma linguagem de programação, a linguagem é o VB ou Jscript.

Existe um framework chamado [aspunit](http://aspunit.sourceforge.net) baseado em [junit](http://junit.org), o aspunit é uma implementação VBScript e necessita do IIS 5.0 or IIS 5.1.

Download: https://sourceforge.net/projects/aspunit/files/ (última atualização 2004).

> Na pasta `TestASPUnit` tem um exemplo de teste.

---

Como alternativa também encontrei este https://github.com/rpeterclark/aspunit (esta bem mais atualizado)

### Usando

Este é um exemplo minimo de configuração:

```
<!-- #include file="/Test/Lib/ASPUnit.asp" -->

Call ASPUnit.AddModule( _
    ASPUnit.CreateModule( _
        "Simple Tests", _
        Array( _
            ASPUnit.CreateTest("TestSomething"), _
            ASPUnit.CreateTest("TestSomethingElse") _
        ), _
        ASPUnit.CreateLifeCycle("Setup", "Teardown") _
    ) _
)

Call ASPUnit.Run()

Sub Setup() ' Could do something here
End Sub

Sub Teardown() ' Then undo it here
End Sub

Function TestSomething()
    Call ASPUnit.Ok(True, "This assertion should pass")
End Function

Function TestSomethingElse()
    Call ASPUnit.Ok(False, "This assertion should fail")
End Function
```

- **Assertions**

  - `Ok(value, description)`: Testa se o valor é `True`
  - `Equal(actual, expected, description)`: Testa se o valor é igual ao esperado
  - `NotEqual(actual, expected, description)`: Testa se o valor é diferente do esperado
  - `Same(actual, expected, description)`: Testa se a referencia é a mesma do objeto esperado (equivale ao operador `Is`)
  - `NotSame(actual, expected, description)`: Testa se a referencia é diferente do objeto esperado.
- **Requisitos**

  - [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) 1.6+ (1.7+ é recomendado).
  - Se estiver usando Grunt você deve precisar do [grunt-aspunit](https://github.com/rpeterclark/grunt-aspunit).